# How to get the type of a variable in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, mocking, type-inference

How to get the static type of a variable in TypeScript, so you can use it on another variable?

Answer (score 1):

Use `typeof`. Its usage has been extended from JavaScript to work on type definitions.

Especially useful with inferred types, like the example below of a type-safe stub function:

```js
function realFunction() { return 123 }

// Compiles
const stub1: typeof realFunction = () => 456

// Does not Compile: wrong return type
const stub2: typeof realFunction = () => 'string'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague but from the statement `so you can use it on another variable?` I'm guessing you are looking for [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html). In the example below `<T>` is the generic variable. It can now be used as a type. Whoever calls this function can define what T is.

```
function doSomethignWithT<T>(arg: T): T {
  let newVariable: T;
  ...
  return arg;
}

doSomethignWithT<boolean>(true)
```

Comment: This answer works if what you want is reuse the type inside the same function. The typeof solution works for reusing types in other contexts.